# UICollectionView stackview reusable cells issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have Stackview inside a custom UICollectionViewCell, which has an image and label.

```
private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    return imageView
}()

private lazy var textLabel: UILabel = {
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()

    label.font = MUIFont.tiny
    label.numberOfLines = 3

    return label
}()

init() {
let stackView: UIStackView = UIStackview(arrangedSubViews:[imageView, textLabel])
stackView.axis = .vertical
contentview.addSubView(stackView)
// add all four side constraints.
}

struct Model: Codable {
let text: String?
let imageURL: String
}

func setData(model: Model) {
if let text: String = model.text {
label.isHideen = false
label.text = text
}
else {
label.isHidden = true
}
imageView.setImageWithString(model.imageURL)
```

Now the problem is I have 1000's of data so for reusable cells which has only image is not coming full still label space left.It is happening only for re-usable cells.

Can someone explain how can we solve it.

Comment: Please share your code for `setImageWithString(model.imageURL)`. Are you downloading the images from a server? Sounds like you are doing that on the main thread.

Comment: Looks like there are many typos in the code that you posted. Does it even compile?

Comment: Also, if you could share the code of your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method, it would help.

Comment: @koen i am using SDwebImage for images.

Comment: Again, please share the image loading and `cellForItemAt` code.